# Xamarin Forms get html Content from WebView

Tags: html, webview, xamarin.forms

as older posts dont seem to provide a simple way to do this i want to give it another try. Are there some new ideas to get html from Xamarin Forms WebView?
I know there is a way using XLabs with HybridWebView but since this project is not maintained anymore this is no opportunity for me.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that HTML? Would it work for you to download the HTML using a WebClient first, do whatever you need to do with it, then display it in the WebView? You could always create a [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/), or possibly even an [effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/) that gives you what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im binding in a web map application. In that map application the user can select a point and then a popup opens. I need to grab information out of that specific pop up in order to do some other stuff. As the popup doesnt exist when the page is loaded its not an option for me to download from url.

Comment: I was mixing up javascript and html at this point. What i finally have done was using this sample https://github.com/adamped/WebViewJavascript

and adapted one line like this 

document.getElementsByClassName("header".innerHTML);

So I was able to get the desired content declared under the header tag.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! If you found a solution to your own question, you can post an answer yourself and mark it as accepted. While you won't get any rep from it, it lets others know you found a solution to your problem.